# How to apply StyleSheet to childrens of same type than parent excluding the parent?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QWidget` containing some buttons and others `QWidgets`, how do I make a stylesheet applied to the `QWidget` **parent** to affect **only** her `QWidget` children?

Some options I tried:

```
QWidget[objectName!="widget_1"] {
     max-width: 200;
     max-height: 200;
}

QWidget > QWidget {
     max-width: 200;
     max-height: 200;
}

QWidget  QWidget {
     max-width: 200;
     max-height: 200;
}
```

In all options, the style is also applied to the parent.

I was reading the Selector Types: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types

but I still couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Read this line in docs: "Instead of =, you can also use ~= to test whether a Qt property of type QStringList contains a given QString." https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types

I.e. so you should probably not use "!=" but use "~=" instead.

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager i tried with "~=" but it still applies to childs.

Comment: I understood that you wanted to apply it to parent but to have effect on children. I am confused now.

Answer (score 0):

For Example, If you have a UI like this:

[image]

**you can Style specific objects by using `#ObjectName`.
like this:**

```
QPushButton#pb_1,#pb_2  {
     min-width: 100;
     min-height:100;
    background-color: rgb(115, 210, 22);
}
QWidget #widget_1
{
    background-color: rgb(252, 233, 79);
}
QWidget#widget_1,#widget_2
{
border:2px solid red;
}
```

**This is the Result:**

[image]

**you can add Widget Style for specific buttons too because `QPushButton` inherits from `QWidget`.**

like

```
QWidget#widget_1,#widget_2,#pb_1
{
border:2px solid red;
}
```

[image]

You can add Style too all `QWidgets` and then call their parent by calling its name and set different style for parent like this:

```
QWidget {
     border:2px solid red;
}
QWidget#centralwidget {
     border-style:none;
}
```

[image: This is the final result]

Answer (score 0):

Give an object name for your parent widget and set the style sheet like this:

```
#parentWidget QWidget { 
    /* your styles */
}
```

This style sheet matches all instances of `QWidget`'s that are descendants (children, grandchildren, etc.) of a `QObject` with an objectName `parentWidget`. You can also specify the widget's class before '#parentWidget'. Note, that almost all widgets are inherited from `QWidget` class. So the styles will be applied to them too.

[apply styles to children from parent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OK20O.png)

If you want to set styles to direct children, use this:

```
#parentWidget > QWidget { 
    /* your styles */
}
```

If you want only `QWidgets` to get styles (exclude inherited) use this:

```
/* for all descendants */
#parentWidget .QWidget { 
    /* your styles */
}
/* for all direct children */
#parentWidget > .QWidget { 
    /* your styles */
}
```

[styles for only QWidget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txAZu.png)

On this screen styles applied to `QWidget`s only. On the very right is `QFrame` which doesn't receive style.